# Preventing hierachical dependency injection in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

*tl;dr:* **How can I prevent Angular from injecting a custom implementation of the HttpClient in lower level modules? Instead I want to use the standard implementation (e.g. without interceptors) that ships with Angular.**

---

I built an Angular 6 library with Angular CLI. This library also exports a module and a service that provide me with identity management functionality (self written) and use the HttpClientModule to send out requests to the api server.

In my applications I reference this library (via private npm packaging), which works fine.

Recently I stumbled upon HttpInterceptors to extend functionality to the already existing HttpClient from the ngx rocket starter kit. You can find the code to the HttpClient implementation here: https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit/blob/master/src/app/core/http/http.service.ts

When I provide my own implementation of the HttpClient in the providers array of my app module, it seems, that due to Angular hierachical dependency injection, my library will also use the provided custom implementation, eventhough I don't want it to.

*So my question is:*  **How can I prevent Angular from injecting a custom implementation of the HttpClient in lower level modules? Instead I want to use the standard implementation (e.g. without interceptors) in lower level modules.**

What I already tried is providing

```
{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: HttpClient }
```

in my user service (please find the code below) which does not work.

This code is inside my application:

*app.module.ts*

```
/* other module code */
imports: [
   UserModule
],
providers: [
   { provide: HttpClient, useValue: MyOwnHttpClientImplementation }
]
/* other module code */
```

This code is inside the library:

*user.module.ts*

```
/* other module code */
imports: [
    HttpClientModule
    /* At this point, I want to use the standard HttpClient implementation */
],
providers: [
    UserService,
    { provide: HttpClient, useValue: HttpClient }
]
/* other module code */
```

*user.service.ts*

```
/* Here are standard HttpClient .get requests, which unfortunately
   use the interceptors that are being provided by the application that
   uses the library and the user module / service */
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `useClass` instead of `useValue`? `{ provide: HttpClient, useClass: HttpClient }`

Comment: You are correct, eventhough this is not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new injector instance in the constructor of my user service. This way, not the HttpClient from the outside application will be used, but instead the angular implementation:

```
constructor(
    private httpHandler: HttpHandler
) {
    const injector = Injector.create(
        {
            providers: [
                { provide: HttpClient, useClass: HttpClient, deps: [HttpHandler] },
                { provide: HttpHandler, useValue: httpHandler }
            ]
        }
    );

    this.httpClient = injector.get(HttpClient);
}
```